# jquery scroll the height of hovered div

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress loop. Every article has the class ".post". I have a button with the class ".skip" for every .post. When the button is clicked i want the page to be scrolled to the next .post in the loop.

I'm using this

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(".post").each(function(){
            var height = $(".post").height();
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(".skip").click(function(){
                $(window).scrollTop(scroll+height);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Something is done but not as it should!

I mean..the page scrolls on click but with the height of the first .post (no matter what .post the .skip button belongs to)

Help!

The .post container from the wp loop

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="skip">skip</div>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) :  ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
        <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?> 
        <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more">more</a>
</article>
```

Comment: If you could supply a sample of your HTML markup, that would be of great assistance.

Comment: Added in the main post!:) If it can't be solved, is there any other way to achive what i want (A working skip button) ?

Comment: Have you tried my edited answer?

Comment: Yep. That works better. Still, does not pleases me! I'll try to think of a different aproach! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $(".skip").click(function () {
        var height = $(this).parent('article').height();
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(window).scrollTop(scroll + height);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".post .skip").click(function(){
            var height = $(this).parent(".post").height();
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            $(window).scrollTop(scroll+height);
        });
    });
});
```

You can't initialize the var "scroll" outside the click event callback, however this would be 0 (Initial top scroll : top of the page = 0).